# can't use static method in class that implements a interface (Java 17)

Tags: java, class, generics, interface

I have a class `Recipe` that has multiple children classes, i want to make two `static` methods, one that takes a JSON file and returns an object of the child class already casted, and other that returns a List of the child class, and all inside an interface like this:

```java
public interface Builder {
    static <T extends Recipe> T build(File file) throws IOException {
        String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getPath())));
        return (T) T.build(new JSONObject(json));
    }

    static <T extends Recipe> List<T> build(File[] files) throws IOException {
        List<T> recipeList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (File file : files) {
            T r = build(file);

            if (r != null) recipeList.add(r);
        }
        return recipeList;
    }
}
```

However when i implement the interface in the sub-class (i.e. `Sub-Recipe`) i can't use the `static` methods created on the interface

```
Sub-Recipe recipe = Sub-Recipe.build(new File("/path/to/file"));
```

I tried using a `default` method on the interface, but if i do that i wouldn't be able to make a `static` method.

Comment: What's wrong with `Recipe.build(...)`?

Comment: Wait, what's `T.build`? You can't call static methods on type parameters like that. You should probably write a `RecipeBuilder<T extends Recipe>`, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to call the interface static method in a wrong way (I may be wrong by not understanding your exact expectation). But the idea with Java 8 static methods in interfaces is that the static method doesn't belong to a specific object. These methods are not part of a class (that implements that interface) available APIs. To use static methods from an interface **you don't have to create any object**, that is the may idea behind them. In order to call your static methods you have to do it something like this:

```
Sub-Recipe recipe = Builder.build((new File("/path/to/file"));
```

There is no need to create any object when calling static methods from an interface, you can think of that interface just as an "utility library" with general methods that have an implementation defined in interface and that cannot be overridden in the classes that are implementing that interface.